# ReactJS TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new at ReactJS, and I encounter some problems.

I also learned about the `ES6` syntax, and it said the following codes are the same meaning.

1.

```
YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'nba'}, function(videos) {
  this.setState({ videos });
});
```

2.

```
YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'nba'}, (videos) => {
  this.setState({ videos });
});
```

However, the first way threw this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'nba'}, function(videos) {
  this.setState({ videos });
});
```

Throws an error because here `this` inside the callback doesn't refer to the `context of React Component` rather the context of the function itself and hence `setState` is undefined here.

In the second example

```
YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'nba'}, (videos) => {
  this.setState({ videos });
});
```

You are making use of `arrow` function to bind the function to the context of the react component. Another way to do the same would be to use `bind(this)`

```
YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term: 'nba'}, function(videos) {
  this.setState({ videos });
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks, so it seems the tutorial explained wrongly.