# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fishes' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

Hi I'm just trying to figure out why I'm getting this error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'fishes' of undefined. What I'm missing?

My App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  fishes : {},
  order : {}
}
}

addFish(fish) {
var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
// update the state object
this.state.fishes['fish-' + timestamp] = fish;
// set the state
this.setState({ fishes : this.state.fishes });
}

render() {
return (
  <div className="ui container"><br/>
  ...
```

Then my AddFishForm:

```
class AddFishForm extends Component {
createFish(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var fish = {
  name : this.refs.name.value,
  price : this.refs.price.value,
  status : this.refs.status.value,
  desc : this.refs.desc.value,
  image : this.refs.image.value
}

this.props.addFish(fish);
this.refs.fishForm.reset();
}
render() {
return (
    <form className="ui equal width form" ref="fishForm" onSubmit=
     {this.createFish.bind(this)}>
      <div className="fields">
...
```

The message in console looks like this:
[image]

Comment: make sure you have bind the method `addFish` in App component.

Comment: binding issue, Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100279/reactjs-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate/43100307#43100307

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably forgotten to bind your method. 
Also, I recommend to spread your state object when needed.

App.js

```
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    fishes: {},
    order: {}
  }

  // THIS IS MISSING
  this.addFish = this.addFish.bind(this)
}

...

addFish(fish) {
  const timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();

  this.setState({
    fishes: {
      ...this.state.fishes,
      ['fish-' + timestamp]: fish
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you give me some readings (links) about spreading the state? What does "...this" do?

Comment: Absolutely! Not only state per se, but you can handle every JS object or array with spread operator. 
I recommend the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

David Walsh's blog: https://davidwalsh.name/spread-operator

And has a really nice "how-to" around it as well:  https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.md

Answer (score 1):

Your state initialization is fine, but the `addFish` method has the wrong context for `this` since you did not bind/auto-bind it.

Change it to

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        fishes: {},
        order: {}
    }
    this.addFish = this.addFish.bind(this);
}
```